# sequelize - duplicate key value violates unique constraint error after bulkinsert

Tags: node.js, database, sequelize.js

Bulk Insert Code

```
    let userData = [{ id: '1', name: 'User-1' }, { id: '2', name: 'User-1' }]
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return
    queryInterface.bulkInsert('users', userData, {})
  }, 
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => { return queryInterface.bulkDelete('users', null, {}) }
}
```

After successfully inserted data, when I will try to insert a new record, it gives an error.

`postgres_1      | ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_pkey"
postgres_1      | DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.`

Note: 
"id" is already primary, unique and auto incremental.

How can I solve this error?

Comment: please share the code where you are inserting the new recorf

Comment: model.create({ name: 'User-3' })

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `id` in the bulk create and you should be good to go

```
let userData = [{name: 'User-1' }, {name: 'User-1' }]
```

Comment: annoying sequelize bug